# draw a surface from a matrix of points in asymptote latex

Tags: asymptote

Let $S$ be a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$. I have a large set of points $(x, y, z)$ belonging to this surface, and I want to draw it using Asymptote in LaTeX. Here is the version of my code that is not working since it complies with no error but no result is produced. Thank you in advance.

```
import three;
size(200);
currentprojection = perspective(6,3,2);
file in = input("xyz.dat").line();
real[][] a=in;
a=transpose(a);
real[] x = a[0];
real[] y = a[1];
real[] z = a[2];
triple[][] points;
for (int i = 0; i < x.length; ++i) {
  triple[] currentPoint = {(x[i], y[i], z[i])};
  points.push(currentPoint);
}
surface s = surface(points);
draw(s);
```

Comment: Are you sure there is no error? Running your code on asymptote 2.86, I get  an error on `no matching function 'surface(triple[][])'`.

Comment: it compiles with no errors in  Asymptote version 2.78

Comment: it compiles with no errors in  Asymptote version 2.78

Comment: What do you mean by a surface? What you have is a cloud of points only as far as I can see.

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues, I think.

First, the `surface(triple[][])` is part of `graph3`, and not `three`. So you need to `import graph3;` instead.

Secondly, if I read your code correctly, your code stuff all of `xyz.dat` into  essentially a one-dimensional array of `triples` (it has width just 1). This will **not** work for `surface`; the function `surface(triple[][])` builds a wire frame parametrized by the two array dimensions. The way you are stuffing the info into the array, there is no surface to plot, as the whole thing is interpreted as a one dimensional curve.

Comment: how to solve these issus, if you have an idea i will be grateful

Comment: if you have some control over the data file, then the easiest way is to make sure your data is in similar format to what is looked for. otherwise, you have to figure out how to define a triangulation based on the points that are available. This is a problem in computational geometry that presumably people have worked on.

Comment: For example, google search shows me this master's thesis https://www.diva-portal.org/smash/get/diva2:643168/FULLTEXT01.pdf